# Audio Framework feature

Tags: iphone

Does the `Audio Framework` have a for automatically flipping pages or views in sync with audio?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What? Did you even try anything?

Comment: i tried adding timer to sync audio with views but having problem when audio is paused then views are still loading and if invalidate the timer then audio plus views are paused but when resumed audio is playing but views are not updating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. when you start playing the audio, spawn a background thread that checks the audio player's current playback time every 0.1 seconds or so.  when its time to update a view/page, switch the view on the main thread.

you can store the times to switch for each page in a dict or array in a plist.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put... no it doesn't.

If you created something though, it'd be nice to see that code on Git Hub :-).